# chown - Difference between user and user:user

Tags: permissions, chown

What is the difference between:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER
```

and

```
sudo chown $USER
```

Why is it 2 times? Is the one user wrong? When I look at permissions with `namei -l`, I often see things like `root root` or `proxy proxy`.

Why does the owner have to be defined and listed 2 times?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The chown command is used to change the owner and group owner of a file or directory.
Superuser privileges are required to use this command. The syntax of chown looks like
this:

```
chown [owner][:[group]] file...
```

chown can change the file owner and/or the file group owner depending on the first argument of the command. Here are some examples:

`chown owner file` example:

```
chown bob file --> Changes the ownership of the file from its current owner to user bob.
```

`chown owner:group file` example:

```
chown bob:users file --> Changes the ownership of the file from its current owner to user bob and changes the file group owner to group users.
```

`chown :group file` example:

```
 chown :admins file --> Changes the group owner to the group admins. The file owner is unchanged.
```

`chown owner: file` example:

```
chown bob: file --> Change the file owner from the current owner to user bob and changes the group owner to the login group of user bob.
```

Please read this nice tutorial https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups. This show some info about user, groups ,permissions ,...

Comment: Thanks. However, what is the benefit to even using groups? Is it that all of the users grouo owns it, not just bob?

Comment: suppose you want to give permission to some users other than the owner!! this is why use groups, you can make a group for them and give it permissions

Comment: You need groups mainly on server machines that are used for multiple users. Say you have a server where people working for your company on project a and project b have user accounts. You could now grant permission to the company group for the files everybody needs to access, and set the ownership for all project a files to the group "project a". That way, nobody from project b will be able to access project a files.

Comment: Groups are needed on desktop too, e.g. for sudo, dialout, scanning, etc.

Comment: If a user is the owner, will `sudo` ever be needed to execute the file?

Answer (score 6):

It is not `user:user`, but `user:group`.

This is command format

`chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...`

Group of users may include many users. Here is some information regarding groups:

Linux uses groups as a way to organize users. Groups organize collections of accounts, primarily as a security measure. Control of group membership is administered through the /etc/group file, which shows a list of groups and its members. Every user has a default or primary group. When a user logs in, the group membership is set for their primary group. This means that when a user launches a program or creates a file, both the file and the running program will be associated with the user’s current group membership. A user may access other files in other groups, as long as they are also a member of that group and the access permissions are set. To run programs or create a file in a different group, the user must run the newgrp command to switch their current group.

A file is owned by a user and a group. By default it is owned by the user who created the file and his default group, unless it is changed.

In your case user `root` is a member of group `root`.

Comment: What is the difference between user and group? I don't see the difference between `root` and `root root` What does group do? I understand the owner section though

Comment: When you add a user to linux, it creates a group with that name. Group contains users. Lets say you have accounting department and you want your account departments to give read write access. You can add all the people to account group and give the read write permission to relevant folder/file.

Comment: If you run `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group` command you can see complete list of groups in your system. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153390/why-does-every-user-have-his-own-group might help you to understand why there is a group with username

Answer (score 3):

`man chown` gives description and usage and other useful info on `chown` command.

```
NAME
       chown - change file owner and group

SYNOPSIS
       chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
       chown [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
```

Form the info given by man page, we may know that `chown $USER:$USER` changes owner and group of target file to `$USER`, while `chown $USER` only changes owner of target file to `$USER`, leaving group of the target file unchanged.

Details (from man page) follow:

```
Owner  is  unchanged  if  missing.   Group is unchanged if missing, but changed to
login group if implied by a ':' following a symbolic OWNER.  OWNER and  GROUP  may
be numeric as well as symbolic.
```

So `chown $USER:$USER` can be shortened as `chown $USER:`.

Outputs like `root root` from `namei -l` command mean that the owner and group of that file are both set to `root`. That's not owner defined or listed twice. Owner and group are two related but different concepts. And a file always has a owner and a group.

---

As to use `chown` command, great chances are superuser privilege is required, since one is likely to transfer the ownship of a file when using `chown` command. However, that is not always the truth.

Say, we have a user named 'test', who belongs to several groups. `id` command gives following output:

```
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),110(sambashare)
```

And user 'test' owns the following file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 May 27 23:34 test_file
```

Then we can change the group of `test_file` to `sambashare` without superuser privilege, as user 'test' belongs to 'test' group and 'sambashare' group at the same time, user 'test' already owns enough permission to change the group of the file.