# Trouble installing wordpress

Tags: command-line, wordpress

I'm trying to install wordpress, and i'm following an article on the web, and one of the steps is:

> Now, we need to change the permission of the ‘wordpress‘ directory. Prompt to the wordpress directory in the root directory we just copied and run the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R username:www-data *
> ```
>
> This command will assign the control of our wordpress directory to www-data user. This is a user web servers used to access the files. In this way the server would be able to write directly to our wordpress directory.

So I change directories, and go into the wordpress dir that's in root, run the command but get this error code:

```
chown: invalid user: ‘username:www-data’
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to put something other than `username` (the article it does specify this) or do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command, you are supposed to replace `username` with your actual username. You can find out what that is by opening a terminal and entering `whoami`.

You could also replace it with `root` if you wanted, although in this case you should add your user to the `www-data` group with `sudo usermod -a -G www-data username`.

See also:

- [Changing user and group permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/628898)
- [Adding a user to a group](https://askubuntu.com/a/79566)

Comment: Thank you, i tried replacing it with my username, but it did not work. But it worked with root. I think it does not work with my username since there is some kind of problem with it even when i run other commands theres always this "warning" i guess which says "sudo: unable to resolve host *username*" .

Comment: @LuanL In the terminal enter `whoami` and see if the result is the same as what you think your username is.

Comment: It is not actually. Never even checked.